# Use the partial fraction to evaluate $\int \frac{\left(3y^2+3y+2\right)}{\left(y^2-1\right)\left(y+1\right)}dy$.

Tags: calculus

$\int \frac{\left(3y^2+3y+2\right)}{\left(y^2-1\right)\left(y+1\right)}dy$

My try：

$\int \frac{\left(3y^2+3y+2\right)}{\left(y^2-1\right)\left(y+1\right)}dy$ ＝
$\int \frac{\left(3y^2+3y+2\right)}{\left(y-1\right)(y+1)\left(y+1\right)}dy$

$\frac{A}{y-1}+\frac{B}{y+1}+\frac{C}{y+1}$ = $\frac{A(y+1)(y+1)+B(y-1)y+1)+C(y-1)(y+1)}{(y-1)(y+1)(y+1)}$ = $\frac{\left(3y^2+3y+2\right)}{\left(y-1\right)(y+1)\left(y+1\right)}$

so that 
$A(y+1)(y+1)+B(y-1)y+1)+C(y-1)(y+1)=Ay^2+2Ay+A+By^2-B+Cy^2-C=3y^2+3y+2$

And then I got

A+B+C=3

2A=3

A-B-C=2

=>A=3/2 B=? C=?
And then I found that I cannot figure out the value of BandC. What is wrong with my steps? I am so confusing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format $$\frac{3y^2+3y+2}{\left(y-1\right)\left(y+1\right)^2}=\dfrac{A}{y-1}+\dfrac{B}{y+1}+\dfrac{C}{(y+1)^2}.$$

Actually this happens because of:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{3y^2+3y+2}{\left(y-1\right)\left(y+1\right)^2}
& =\dfrac{A}{y-1}+\dfrac{By+C}{(y+1)^2}\\
& =\dfrac{A}{y-1}+\dfrac{B(y+1)+(C-B)}{(y+1)^2}\\
& =\dfrac{A}{y-1}+\dfrac{B}{y+1}+\dfrac{C-B}{(y+1)^2}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The doubled factor $(y+1)^2$, does not contribute $\frac{B}{y+1}+\frac{C}{y+1}$. It contributes $\frac{B}{y+1}+\frac{C}{(y+1)^2}$.